# start a new activity from each listView item selected

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment listView,on this list is a image and a textview.
I would like to click each item on the list to start a new activity! tried an onItemClickListener but but cant seem to start a new activity,the current onItemClickListener displays toast text when clicked.

I have tried removing the toast and adding an intent to no avail.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Button showBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final PlayersFragment p = new PlayersFragment();
        showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                showBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, p);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (showBtn != null) {
            showBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PlayersFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

    ListView lv;
    String[] players = {"image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7",
            "image8", "image9", "image10", "image11", "image12", "image13", "image14"};

    int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8, R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,
            R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12, R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14,};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);

        //initialize listview
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //create adapter obj and set list view to it
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), players, images);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), players[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what code did you wrote to start the `Activity` ? can you add that too

Comment: in the onItemclickListener i used Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerFragment)
start.image1.activity;
start.image2.activity;

Comment: you should do like this to startActivity -> `getActivity().startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use onItemClicklistener for your listview :

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
                if(pos == 0)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(pos == 1)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , Activity3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } and so on .......
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi Pirisok, would this work in the current onItemClickListener by removing the toast?

Comment: you must setOnItemClickListener for your listview not a button , if you do this , the value of pos indicate the row number of your listview , this how , you can start activities from clicking every row of listview.

Comment: @james ,  if you replace lv.setonitemclick listener of your code , with the one that i suggest , it will work for you.

Comment: Pirisok, thank you so much, this has worked, very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for start : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Then in your listener, call startActivity by PlayersFragment.this.getActivity().startActivity() or something like that

Comment: thats what i have been trying in the onClick prior to asking for help

Comment: Can you show your code for launch activity inside the listener ?